# MySQL Multiple counts in one query with case

Tags: mysql

Good day,

I have compiled the following query.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN `booking_creationdate` LIKE '2020-01-31%' THEN 1 END) AS 2020-01-31,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN `booking_creationdate` LIKE '2020-02-05%' THEN 1 END) AS 2020-02-05
FROM `bookingstable` AND `booking_location` = 4
```

But I am kinda stuck.

I get the following error :

```
PDO Message :
0   : 42000
1   : 1064
2   : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2020-01-31, COUNT(CASE WHEN `booking_creationdate` LIKE '2020-02-05%' THEN ' at line 2
3   : Table : not set : DBA::QUERY()

faulty query :  

SELECT
COUNT(CASE WHEN `booking_creationdate` LIKE '2020-01-31%' THEN 1 END) AS 2020-01-31,
COUNT(CASE WHEN `booking_creationdate` LIKE '2020-02-05%' THEN 1 END) AS 2020-02-05
FROM `bookingstable` AND `booking_location` = 4
```

If I wouldn't have set the table. The problem would be clear. But I have.
I know you can setup this query in another way. But the AS statement is something that makes it very workable for me. As I am not really a MySQL champion. (* it is on my to-do list for this year to make a personal MySQL performance increase though ;-))

I hope someone can point me at my mistake(s) here.

TIAD

**EDIT**

> **Solution**
>   *Solution as provided by "Pankaj_Dwivedi"*
>
> ```
> SELECT
>     COUNT(CASE WHEN booking_creationdate LIKE '2020-01-31%' THEN 1 END) AS "2020-01-31",
>     COUNT(CASE WHEN booking_creationdate LIKE '2020-02-05%' THEN 1 END) AS "2020-02-05"
> FROM bookingstable AND booking_location = 4
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is problem with quotes in query :
Try below:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN booking_creationdate LIKE '2020-01-31%' THEN 1 END) AS "2020-01-31",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN booking_creationdate LIKE '2020-02-05%' THEN 1 END) AS "2020-02-05"
FROM bookingstable AND booking_location = 4
```

Comment: Cannot accept your comment just yet :-D THNX!! (will wait 5 mins before accepting it.. so limit :-)

Answer (score 0):

`-` isn't allowed in identifiers unless the identifier is enclosed in back ticks. So instead of

```
... AS 2020-01-31
```

write

```
... AS `2020-01-31`
```

and analog for all other cases. Or use another alias without `-`.

Side note: It seems like `booking_creationdate` is a string. That's the wrong data type. Use some date/time data type.